# jquery-mobile - how can I bind disable ajax links to a certain class

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I working on a multicolumn layout in Jquery Mobile.

When the user opens a multicolumn page, I want to disable the JQM ajaxlinks navigation (and switch to "artificial navigation and history". So basically I'm trying to bind to a link or list item with a class name ="ui-hash-blocked". When the user leaves the page, I'm switching ajaxlinks back on.

I like the idea but cannot get this code to work (Error: $.mobile' [undefined])

```
$('.ui-hash-block').click(function ()
             {
             $.mobile.ajaxLinksEnabled = false;               
             });
```

Is there anything wrong with the syntax?

I know the error from calling $.mobile before initiating JQM, but since I'm only calling this function when the link/list item is clicked, JQM should have already been initiated.

Thanks for help & Merry Xmas!

Frequent

PS: if you need more code, I can put a up an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
  //Disable ajax link
  $('.disable-ajax').click(function(event){
    $.mobile.ajaxFormsEnabled = false;
  });
});
```

Comment: a little late :-) but I will try. Thanks.

Answer (score 18):

Add `data-ajax="false"` to the link if you only want this behavior on certain links

Comment: how can i disable ajax to <input type="image">...?

Answer (score 0):

This $.mobile.* is a bunch of configuration options that are being used quite early. That's why they show [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a2/#docs/api/globalconfig.html) when to initialize it. This setting is a global one.

What you're trying to do is hacky. But I belive you can change the setting in the correct moment, which should be one of these:

1. just before the click - try mousedown event insteqad of click in your example
2. before the item is being pimped with JQM:

   $.mobile.ajaxLinksEnabled = false;
   $('theNEWelement').appendTo('somewhere').page();
   $.mobile.ajaxLinksEnabled = false;

Comment with results and I will edit to mark which one worked. I can't test it at the moment.