# Why is my jQueryMobile CSS Style being applied to a linked page?

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I am using a jQuery CSS style on the main portion of [my website](http://www.annuit.com/opensource.html).  It works fine.  Now, I also have a [sub-directory of my website](http://www.annuit.com/jquerytent/) which should not use the style.  When I manually navigate my browser to the sub-directory of the website, no style is applied which is what I want.  When I click on a link to the sub-directory from the main area, however, it is applying the CSS style from the main part even though I am not referencing this CSS anywhere in the HTML of that sub-directory.  If I refresh the browser, the style goes away.

Please can someone help me understand what is going on here?  Thank you.

Comment: Which browser are you using? (including the version number)

Comment: @Daniel Bank: Not until you provide more information as to your site's url structure, your link's html etc...

Comment: It has to be something in the JavaScript. After the page loads, if you disable JavaScript and then click the link, it loads without styles.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using jquery mobile, which by default loads the content of links via ajax. That means you don't have a page refresh when clicking on a link. The contents get dynamically inserted in your document which still has all your css.

More information here.
http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-links.html

You have to disable ajax for that link. More information here.
[jquery-mobile - how can I bind disable ajax links to a certain class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517228/jquery-mobile-how-can-i-bind-disable-ajax-links-to-a-certain-class)

Answer (score 0):

Clear your history and browser data, then refresh and try.

> 1. Try to open the link in chrome and using the developer options (F12)
>      look for the resources it is referencing. If the page is referencing
>      the CSS files then either Javascript is making the referencing or
>      you have accidentally kept the resource link. Let the forum know your findings.

Edit
Somebody seems to have done what I have mentioned and has come to conclusions that they are because of AJAX. The steps I have mentioned above would let you do that all by yourself.